# Stripping image tags within sql query without function

Tags: html, mysql, sql, strip

I am running the following query again a MySql Wordpress database and it returns 1 record like it should. However, within the record there is an `<img.../img>` tag that I do not want in the results.

```
SELECT 
        meta_value 
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE 
        wp_postmeta.post_id = ID 
        AND meta_key = 'scientific_content'
```

I have looked around and found functions to do this, however, because I am using a MySQL Database for Wordpress and I cannot use or create a function.

How would i strip the image tags within the query?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(LEFT(meta_value, LOCATE('<img', meta_value) - 1),   -- get the position before the <
       RIGHT(meta_value, LENGTH(meta_value) - 4 - LOCATE('/img>', meta_value))) -- get the position after the >
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'scientific_content'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c32b21/4

This assumes there's one and only one `<img>` tag that's always properly closed...